# Do solder-mount screws exist?

Tags: mount

I have a small circuit board that has no mounting holes but does provide unpopulated test point pads. Is there any option for machine screws or standoffs that I could solder into these for mounting the board?

Comment: Ah you mean like that.

Comment: Why not foam tape pads?

Comment: @Passerby: No reason per se, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 10):

Surface mount, reflow solderable stand-offs are available, for low mechanical stress applications.

See for instance the [PEM ReelFast SMT product range](http://www.pemnet.com/fastening_products/pdf/smtdata.pdf). They offer spacers, nuts and snap fasteners in a range of sizes. These do not require plated through holes.

The parts come in the reel with removable Kapton patches on top, covering the holes, for vacuum pick-up, so they can be used for pick-and-place assembly as well.